# Converting Bar chart to star/polar chart in report builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have created a bar chart but want to convert it to a star/polar chart. When I do this none of my categories are showing

I've tried filters, groupings etc in chart properties. Is there something different about star charts?